# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable with itextpdf-5.5.6

Tags: java, itextpdf

I'm using itextpdf-5.5.6.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar, and getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:149)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(PdfReader.java:1013)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1411)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:721)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:395)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:415)
at ca.zdata.pdf.populate.PdfFormEditor.getPopulatedForm(PdfFormEditor.java:182)
```

in the line:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
```

where "is" - ByteArrayInputStream

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

IText 5.5.6 depends on bcprov-jdk15on **1.49**, not 1.48. See [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.itextpdf%7Citextpdf%7C5.5.6%7Cjar).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it worked with bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar